# string* [] in c++ converts to string[] in c#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I am a beginner in dot net. My Doubt is the following:- In a dll a function takes `string* []` as one of its parameters. Now this method needs to be used in c#. This dll reference is added to c# project. Now in c# project when pressing f12 i.e "Go to definition" for this function, it displays `string[]` in place of `string* []` and long in place of long long in function prototype, e.g :- Suppose in dll the function looks like-

```
public void fn(long long a, string* attributeNames[]) {....}
```

Now in C#-

After adding dll reference to current c# project. F12 is pressed on function name, then in Meta Data it displays following function prototype-

```
public void fn(long a, string[] attributeNames);
```

This dll is wrapper that contains both managed as well as unmanaged code.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is your question?!

Comment: why string* [] converts to string[] and long long to long ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ is converted to IL which is translated to C# in the metadata.

You don't need to explicitly define pointers in C#, reference types are implicitly pointers. That is why `string* attributeNames[]` converts to `string[] attributeNames`

`long long` in C++ is a 64 bit integer which in C# is the `long`

Comment: Can u please tell some more conversions like this ?

Comment: Try this link for more: http://www.binaryfortress.com/News/2010/04/converting-c-data-types-to-c/